# Angular6: dropdown menu in my navigation is not closing

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

when I click on the button the drop-down menu is popping up but it's not closing automatically when i click on the another menu

this project is created on Angular6 and bootstrap4

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown-content dropdown" dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link" dropdownToggle role="button"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Consumers</a>
      <ul *dropdownMenu  class="subnav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/guru">Overview</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">InActive</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>  
<li class="nav-item dropdown-content dropdown" dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link" dropdownToggle role="button"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>UserList</a>
      <ul *dropdownMenu  class="subnav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/guru">Overview</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">InActive</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

I want to close this menu automatically when I press on another menu or on that menu.

Comment: can you replicate in on stackbliz?

Comment: sure sir, here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwo8hf-77y2jm

Comment: OK, what browser should i use. Because in chrome it works. Or maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: Sir,  it will work only if I click on that. I want it to close when I click on another menu with submenu